# How should I Schedule SQL Server 2008 queries to run every month?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to schedule some queries to run at the beginning of every month (for monthly reports) and I read that creating a JOB in sql server 2008 was the way to go. Unfortunately, I don't have the rights/privileges to use SQL Server Agent at this time. Is there another way of scheduling a few queries to run the first day of every month?

I am running Sql Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard operating system.

Comment: What do you want to do with the output of the queries? Look at it, send it to a file, or ...?

Comment: If these genuinely are reports, why not write them in reporting services (RS) and set up a monthly subscription for them? That functionality is built into RS.

Comment: the output of the queries would ideally be saved as excel files or as .csv files. @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't know why I didn't think of that. I will give that a try.

Comment: If the point of running the query is to make an xl/csv once a month and send it to people, then RS is the way to go.  Create a report in reporting services that generates the results you want, and then create a subscription that sends it to the right people on the right days.  (once a month is one of the options).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Jobs is indeed the right way about it.

If you don't have the permissions, talk to your manager/DBA in order to set up the job.

If this is not possible, you can use the [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) in conjunction with [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to execute queries on the SQL Server.

Another alternative is to write a [windows service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) that will execute these queries, but in terms of scheduling I would trust the task scheduler over custom code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try talking first to the DBA (but hes new on the job so he's a little paranoid and thinks that any little thing will cause the serve to explode! lol) if i still cant get the permissions then i'll try one of the other methods you have listed.

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server Agent really is the best way to do it so try and get access if you need it.

If you have to, you could create a 'hack' - one possible way is to find a stored proc that you know gets called at least daily and add a final step in there to check if `DATEPART('dd', getdate()) = 1`. If so, call your other proc that you'd like to be 'scheduled'.

Ugly, but would work if needed!

Comment: hehehe cool,  I'll keep that in mind in case all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely cannot use SQL jobs to do it, you could use C# to write a program which connects to the database and runs the queries.  Then, compile this program into an executable and write a batch job which runs the executable from Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

We use [AutoSQL](http://www.autosql.net) in our office. It requires no access to specific services, only a connection to SQL server and task scheduler. It's user friendly and outputs to Excel, CSV and email.